# Can A Deleted Material From A Fractured Object Be Re-applied?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am creating an animated fractured object. Initally, when I created the fracture, it included a second material for the inside of the mesh (shown in black). Unfortunately, I deleted the 2nd material. Is there anyway to add the second material back onto all the objects without applying it one-by-one?

[image: Image of a fractured object and it's two seperate materials]

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you delete the material? I can't get the same black result like your screenshot. If I delete the slot like in your screenshot, the unassigned faces use the remaining  material and don't appear black.

Comment: I selected all the objects at one time and then deleted the black material by removing it from the material slot.

Comment: Hm.. I can't seem to reproduce the same conditions as in your screenshot. Did you happen to enable *save vertex groups* when fracturing? Then you could use some python to recreate and assign materials..

Comment: No, did nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select one piece and add your second material again.
Then select all of the other parts and select that one part with the second material as the active object (select it as last object). Then press Ctrl+L and click on materials!

Comment: It is not clear. How can I select all of the other fractures while selecting only the black face of the one piece?

Comment: Are those faces asigned to a material?

Comment: They were before I deleted the material. But now it's as if they are still assigned to a second material but they aren't.

Comment: I dont think my solution is possible without braking your animation: join all the pieces together and then deselect everything in editmode, then select all faces asigned to the material (it's a button under your material slot), then select invers and asign a new material to the selected faces. Then select everything and hit P and choose 'By loose parts' hope this works